# The inequality related with normal distribution

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution

When $Z \sim N(0,1)$, then $P(\vert Z\vert \gt t)\le\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}\times \frac{exp(-t^2/2)}t$.

My question is: I can get the aboving inequality, but how can I get the inequality such that  $P(\vert Z\vert \gt t)\le\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}\times \frac{t}{1+t^2} \times exp(-t^2/2)$?

Comment: Does this new $Z$ follow normal(0,1)

Comment: Yes. Z follows standard normal distribution.

Comment: @Qwerty Yes, $Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$. Or what do you mean by 'new $Z$ ' ?

Comment: I dont understand your question. How can the same Z follow the 2nd inequality if it follows the first but the second is not implied by the first?

Comment: I can get the first inequality. But for my supervisor asking, I need to figure out the second inequality. It's the same Z, not a new one.

Comment: How did you get the first inequality ?

Comment: This is the answer link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723041/mills-inequality-on-normal-distribution?rq=1

Comment: The first one is the Mill's inequality.

Comment: The [continued fraction for the error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Continued_fraction_expansion) can be used to derive a formula of the desired form. Stop at $a_1$ and your factor $t/(1+t^2)$ appears.

Answer (score 0):

[We have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Continued_fraction_expansion)
$$1-\text{erf}(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-x^2)\frac{1}{x^2+(1/2)/q}$$
with $q\geq 1$. Thus
$$1-\text{erf}(x)\geq\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-x^2)\frac{1}{x^2+(1/2)}$$
Now 
$$P(|Z|>t)=P(Z>t)+P(Z<-t)\\
=2P(Z>t)\\
=2\left(1-\frac{1}{2}(1+\text{erf}(t/\sqrt{2}))\right)\\
=1-\text{erf}(t/\sqrt{2})$$
$$1-\text{erf}(t/\sqrt{2})\geq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\exp(-t^2/2)\frac{t}{t^2+1}$$
[This looks right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-erf%28t%2Fsqrt%282%29%29+,+sqrt%282%2Fpi%29*t%2F%28t%5E2%2B1%29*exp%28-t%5E2%2F2%29+,+sqrt%282%2Fpi%29*exp%28-t%5E2%2F2%29%2Ft+from+0+to+5).

Comment: What I need is "less or equal".

Comment: Your inequality is wrong. You can see this by setting $t=0$: $P(|Z|>0)=1/2$ , $\sqrt{2/\pi}\frac{0}{1+0}\exp(0)=0$. Greater than or equal is correct.

Comment: From the first one inequality, I can derive that $t \neq 0$. Now I want to get the boundary for t such that $t \ge 1$, that's why I need to get the second inequality.

Comment: So If do not consider $t = 0$, then how can I drive the second inequality by using error function.

Comment: These inequalities hold for all $t$ (at least all positive $t$). Your original inequality is *never* true.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks.