# Can we use the Chebyshev's inequality like Markov

Tags: inequality

The Markov equality gives us the probability that our RV takes a value less than a threshold and the Chebyshev's inequality gives the probability of being in a certain range of the mean.

Can we use the Chebyshev's inequality like the Markov`s (i.e. to get the probability of being less than the threshold)? Lastly, if it is known that our distribution is normal is it wise to use Chebyshev's inequality?

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks first. Markov inequality gives us $\textit{an estimate}$ (or an upper bound) of the probability that the RV takes values greater than a threshold, same for Chebyschev's inequality and the probability of being outside of a certain range of the mean. Chebyschev inequality is a direct consequence of Markov's one applied to $\vert X-\mathbb{E}[X]\vert^2$. recall that Markov's inequality holds only if the RV is nonnegative, so is not suitable for any RV unless you use it on $\vert X\vert$ instead. Now if you want to obtain a Markov-like inequality using Chebyschev you could do the following: if $t\geq \mathbb{E}[X]$, then
$$\begin{split} \mathbb{P}(X\geq t) & = \mathbb{P}(X-\mathbb{E}[X]\geq t-\mathbb{E}[X])\\
& \leq \mathbb{P}(\vert X-\mathbb{E}[X]\vert \geq t-\mathbb{E}[X])
\leq \dfrac{Var(X)}{(t-\mathbb{E}[X])^2} \end{split}$$
where in the last passage Chebyschev's was used (at least this is a possible way, probably there are better estimates). In the special case in which $X$ is normal, much better estimates are known, as $\textbf{Mill's inequality}$, see [Mill's Inequality on normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723041/mills-inequality-on-normal-distribution) for example.